# IsolationForest is always predicting 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am working with a project to detect `out-of-domain` text input, with the help of `IsolationForest` and `tf-idf` feature. Following is my works in summarized form:

**TRAINING**

- **On tfidf:**

  - Fit and transform in-domain dataset using `CountVectorizer()`.
  - Fit a tfidftransformer() with my with this `CountVectorizer()` and save the transformer (to use it during test time).
  - Therefore, transform the training data using `tfidftransformer()`
  - Save both `CountVectorizer()`'s `vocabulary_` and `TfidfTransformer()` object using `pickle` for test time usage.
- **On IsolationForest:**

  - Collect the transformed in-domain dataset and train a `IsolationForest()` novelity detector.
  - Save the model using `joblib`.

**TESTING:**

- Load all of the saved models.
- Get the tfidf transformed feature of current out-of-domain input text after replicating all the steps (transformations only) similar to training step.
- Predict if it is out-of-domain or not, using the saved `IsolationForest` model.

But what I have found even if the tf-idf feature is quite different for each of my test input, the `IsolationForest` always predicting 1.

What is probably going wrong?

NB: I also tried inputting dummy vectors to `IsolationForest` model by mimicking the output of `tf-idf` transformer to make sure if the `tf-idf` module is responsible for this or not but no matter which random vector I provide I always get 1 as output from `IsolationForest`. Also note that, `tf-idf` has a lot of features (tokens), in my case the count is 48015.

Comment: If any further explanation needed, please feel free to ask. Thanks.